# Serilog doesnt create index on ElasticSearch and i dont know why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, docker-compose, serilog

I have coding Docker Compose, Asp.Net Core 6, Elastic Stack etc. Elastic Stack succesfully running. Serilog succesfully log in console but unsuccesful log in ElasticSearch. [My Github Repo](https://github.com/Filiphasan/MediatrExample).
I use this package:

- Serilog.AspNetCore
- Serilog.Enrichers.Environment
- Serilog.Exceptions
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration
- Serilog.Sinks.Debug
- Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch

My Docker Compose file is:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

networks:
    mediatrexample:
        driver: bridge
    elk_stack:
        driver: bridge

services:
    pgsql_image:
        image: postgres:latest
        container_name: postgersql_db
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "123456"
            POSTGRES_DB: "ecommerce"
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        networks:
            - mediatrexample

    redis_image:
        image: 'redis:latest'
        container_name: redis_db
        restart: always
        environment:
            - REDIS_PASSWORD=RRnFPZ93tjBHB9W62p
            - REDIS_PORT=6379
        ports:
            - '6379:6379'
        command: [ "redis-server" ]
        networks:
            - mediatrexample

    elastic_image:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.1
        container_name: elk_elastic
        environment:
            - node.name=elastic01
            - xpack.monitoring.enabled=true
            - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
            - xpack.security.audit.enabled=true
            - discovery.type=single-node
            - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=DkIedPPSCb
            - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
        ulimits:
            memlock:
                soft: -1
                hard: -1
        networks:
            - elk_stack
        ports:
            - 9200:9200
            - 9300:9300

    kibana_image:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.1
        container_name: elk_kibana
        environment:
            - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elastic_image:9200
            - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elastic_image:9200
            - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
            - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=DkIedPPSCb
        networks:
            - elk_stack
        depends_on:
            - elastic_image
        links:
            - elastic_image
        ports:
            - 5601:5601

    mediatrexample.api:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mediatrexampleapi
        container_name: mediatr_example
        depends_on:
            - pgsql_image
            - redis_image
            - elastic_image
            - kibana_image
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: MediatrExample.API/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - mediatrexample
        ports:
            - 5001:80 
        links:
            - pgsql_image
            - redis_image
            - elastic_image
        environment:
            - CONNECTIONSTRINGS__NpgSQLConnection=User ID=postgres;Password=123456;Host=pgsql_image;Port=5432;Database=ecommerce
            - Redis__Host=redis_image
            - Redis__Port=6379
            - Redis__Password=RRnFPZ93tjBHB9W62p
            #- Serilog__WriteTo__1__Args__nodeUris=http://elastic:DkIedPPSCb@elastic_image:9200
```

My Log Configuration Code is:

```cs
public static class MyLogger
    {
        public static void ConfigureSeriLog(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            string elasticUser = configuration["SeriLogConfig:ElasticUser"];
            string elasticPassword = configuration["SeriLogConfig:ElasticPassword"];

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .WriteTo.Debug()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(configuration["SeriLogConfig:ElasticUri"]))
                {
                    AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                    AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv7,
                    IndexFormat = $"{configuration["SeriLogConfig:ProjectName"]}-{configuration["SeriLogConfig:Environment"]}-logs-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
                    ModifyConnectionSettings = s => s.BasicAuthentication(elasticUser, elasticPassword),
                    FailureCallback = e => { Console.WriteLine("Hasan - Unable to submit event -- " + e.MessageTemplate); e.Properties.Values.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write(x)); },
                    EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog |
                                   EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToFailureSink |
                                   EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback |
                                   EmitEventFailureHandling.ThrowException,
                    FailureSink = new FileSink("./failures.txt", new JsonFormatter(), null)
                })
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", configuration["SeriLogConfig:Environment"])
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration, "SerilogLogLevels")
                .CreateLogger();
        }
    }
```

My Program.cs Code is:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var Configuration = builder.Configuration;
// Add services to the container.

MyLogger.ConfigureSeriLog(Configuration);
builder.Host.UseSerilog();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
    {
        opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWTTokenOptions:SecretKey"])),
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), //Skew default 5 minute
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var multiplexer = RedisUtility.ConnectRedis(Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(multiplexer);

builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GetAllUserRequest)));
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddMyServiceLifeCycles(Configuration);
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GetAllUserRequestValidator)));
builder.Services.ConfigureMyOptionModels(Configuration);

builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("NpgSQLConnection"), npsqlOpt =>
    {
        npsqlOpt.CommandTimeout(150);
        npsqlOpt.MigrationsAssembly("MediatrExample.Data");
    });
});
// Above Code for "timestamp with time zone' literal cannot be generated for Local DateTime: a UTC DateTime is required" error solution
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

builder.Services.AddCors(options => { options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", policy => policy.AllowAnyOrigin()); });

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMyCustomMiddleware();

app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapGet("/", () =>
{
    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateAsyncScope())
    {
        var service = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var logger = service.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogInformation("Example Log Date: {0}", DateTime.Now);
    }
    return "Server is Running...";
});

#region Auto Run Pending Migration
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateAsyncScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    if (dbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
    {
        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
#endregion

app.Run();
```

My appsetting.json file is:

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "NpgSQLConnection": "User ID=postgres;Password=123456;Host=pgsql_image;Port=5432;Database=ecommerce;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;"
  },
  "Environment": {
    "EnvironmentName": "dev"
  },
  "Redis": {
    "Host": "0.0.0.0",
    "Port": "6380",
    "Password": "123456"
  },
  "JWTTokenOptions": {
    "SecretKey": "v5PSdoOHjeB34wUkmMwr4x4Z1HWkudFoyVZTx7sFvm",
    "TokenExpireTimeMinute": 120
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch", "Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Elasticsearch",
        "Args": {
          "nodeUris": "http://localhost:9200",
          "indexFormat": "mediatr-example-logs-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
          "autoRegisterTemplate": true,
          "autoRegisterTemplateVersion": "ESv7",
          "DetectElasticsearchVersion": true,
          "OverwriteTemplate": true,
          "emitEventFailure": "WriteToSelfLog",
          "registerTemplateFailure": "IndexAnyway",
          "numberOfShards": 20,
          "numberOfReplicas": 10,
          "connectionGlobalHeaders": "Authorization=Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpEa0llZFBQU0Ni"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName" ]
  },
  "SerilogLogLevels": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "SeriLogConfig": {
    "ProjectName": "mediatr-example",
    "ElasticUri": "http://localhost:9200",
    "Environment": "development",
    "ElasticUser": "elastic",
    "ElasticPassword": "DkIedPPSCb"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I have triesd two ways for Serilog logging on Elastic Stack but each way doesnt work.

1. Serilog Configuration Set in MyLogger.ConfigureSeriLog
2. Serilog Configuration Set in appsetting.json

Please help Why Serilog doesn't logging on Elastic Stack?

Comment: Are your logs appearing anywhere in Elastic? You could need to actually create the index to be shown in the settings?

Comment: How you check whether index is created? Are you checking through Kibana or directly from Elasticsearch?